# How to make service control policy immune for certain user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloud, devops, aws-policies

I have created an SCP for tag enforcement in EC2 instance, and it doesn't work for elastic beanstalk because I can't manually add the enforced tags to ec2 in elastic beanstalk. so I am trying to immune that policy for certain user.

[image]

Comment: You need to provide more information. What does the SCP look like?